# Compare 2 values on 2 different webpages using RFT

Tags: rft

How can I compare values based on another page, either using data pool values or get values from another page, in `Rational Functional Tester`  using java?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Some tips to improve your question: People are more likely to answer, if you describe what you already tried and where exactly you need help :)

Comment: 0

down vote

favorite


 


I would like compare values in one web page based on the values in different web page in Rational Functional Tester using java.